# what do these android permissions mean and how to use them?

Tags: android, permissions

I came across these types of android permissions:

```
INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW
MANAGE_APP_TOKENS
REORDER_TASKS
SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER
```

but they are unfamiliar to me.
Could somebody explain what do they permit? 
In what situations are they likely to be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are all internal system facilities, so not available to applications.  Technically the symbols shouldn't be in the SDK documentation, but we missed @hide-ing them for 1.0.  You can look at the platform source where they are used to see what they protect.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions and their uses can be found here in the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: yes, I found them there - but their explanations are quite basic. I can't understand what are these permissions REALLY used for? maybe a usage example could do more?